# Can you add percentages to elements of a pie chart using Openpyxl in Python?

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I have a pie chart in excel file which I created with Openpyxl.

[image: Pie Chart Created]

Is there a way to add percentages to every element in the pie chart like the below image for example?

[image: Example of desired pie chart]

For some further context, the excel file is created in Python. I have isolated the code segment that creates the pie chart from my code:

```
from openpyxl import Workbook
from openpyxl.chart import PieChart, Reference

imd=30
lid=18.5
cad=10
wad=12
rud=16.5
sad=0
ht=12
othd=40


wb = Workbook()  
sheet = wb.active
sheet.title="Data"

fi,ft=[],[]
sheet['C11'] = imd
sheet['C12'] = lid
sheet['C13'] = cad
sheet['C14'] = wad
sheet['C15'] = rud
sheet['C16'] = sad
sheet['C17'] = ht
sheet['C18'] = othd


sheet2 = wb.create_sheet()
sheet2.title='Charts'

pie=PieChart()

labels = Reference(sheet, min_col=1, min_row=11, max_row=18)
data = Reference(sheet, min_col=3, min_row=10, max_row=18)
pie.add_data(data, titles_from_data=True)
pie.set_categories(labels)
pie.title = "Pie Chart"

sheet2.add_chart(pie, 'A1')

wb.save("temp.xlsx")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can add labels to your chart with the "**DataLabelList**"

**SOLUTION** - Following your code, add the import and then set the object:

```py
from openpyxl.chart.label import DataLabelList

pie=PieChart()

labels = Reference(sheet, min_col=1, min_row=11, max_row=18)
data = Reference(sheet, min_col=3, min_row=10, max_row=18)
pie.add_data(data, titles_from_data=True)
pie.set_categories(labels)
pie.title = "Pie Chart"

#Set the DataLabelList.
pie.dataLabels = DataLabelList()

#Show the percent on the labels.
pie.dataLabels.showPercent = True

sheet2.add_chart(pie, 'A1')
```

Also you have the following options:

- **pie.dataLabels.showPercent** = True #To show the percentage
- **pie.dataLabels.showCatName** = True #To show the value name
- **pie.dataLabels.showLeaderLines** = True #This option have a bug, but it should show the leader lines of each label on the chart.
- **pie.dataLabels.position** = "outEnd" #To set the position of the label (options: 'bestFit', 'b', 'ctr', 'inBase', 'inEnd', 'l', 'outEnd', 'r', 't')
- **pie.dataLabels.separator** = "\n" # To set the separator inside the label.
- **pie.dataLabels.showVal** = True # To show the value.

**Version: openpyxl~=3.0.10**

I hope I have helped you :D

Comment: Thanks, I have tested it and it works. I have since moved on to xlsxwriter for my code, but I'm verifying this in case somebody using Openpyxl has this question in the future.

Answer (score 0):

First you will need to iterate through all your variables to change the number to a decimal percentage by dividing the number by 100. Then change the cell number format to a percentage.

```
sheet['C11'] = imd/100  # convert to decimal
sheet['C11'].number_format = '0.0%'  # change to percentage
```

Then you need to generate the data labels and also move the legend position using the first letter of the direction.

```
pie.dataLabels = DataLabelList()  # generate data labels
pie.dataLabels.showVal = True  # shows labels
pie.legend.position = 't'  # move legend to top of chart
```